# Airflow 2.4.3 - Facing Issue while extracting job_id, task_id and task_state of a BigqueryOperator from PythonOperator task

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a use case wherein we have 3 tasks Task1(BigqueryOperator),Task2(PythonOperator) and Task3(PythonOperator).
The flow of execution is [task1 , task2] >> task3
Task3 is triggered after Task1 and Task2. In Task3, I require to fetch the task level information of the previous tasks(Task 1, Task 2) i.e. job_id, task_id, run_id,  state of a task and  url of the tasks.

To my understanding, `context`  object can be used to fetch these details as it is a dictionary that contains various attributes and metadata related to the current task execution.
I am unable to make use of this object for fetching the task level details of a BigQueryOperator.

Tried few approaches:

`Approach 1:` Tried xcom_push and xcom_pull to fetch the details from task instance(ti).

```
def task2(ti, project):
    client = bigquery.Client(project=bq_project)
    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()

    sql_str1 = f"""<some sql>"""

    xvc = client.query(sql_str1,job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()['<some value>'].values.tolist()

    
    print("Task Instance values", ti)
    job_id = ti.job_id 
    run_id = ti.run_id
    task_id = ti.task_id
    #task_status = ti.status # Pass the extracted values to the next task using XCom

    ti.xcom_push(key='task2_job_id', value=job_id)
    ti.xcom_push(key='task2_run_id', value=run_id)
    ti.xcom_push(key='task2_task_id', value=task_id)
    return xvc

def task3(ti,dag_id, task_id, run_id, task_state):
    insert_values = []
    run_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    current_date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    for idx, name in enumerate(all_names):
        if name in ('task1'):  ##If condition is used for PythonOperator
            job_id = ti.xcom_pull(key=f"{name}_job_id")
            task_id = ti.xcom_pull(key=f"{name}_task_id")
        else:                  ## Else condition is for BigQueryOperator
            job_id= ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=f"{name}",key='job_id')
            task_id = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids=f"{name}",key='task_id') ### Not working of Bigquery Opeartor
            
        insert_values.append((name, 1, dag_id, task_id, run_id, job_id, run_date, current_date_time))
    print("Insert values: ", insert_values)
```

This approach is working for PythonOperator only for certain values like job_id, run_id, task_id but not for task state and few others.
For BigQueryOperator, its only fetching job_id but not others

`Approach 2`: Tried airflow context from one of SO links

```
from airflow.models import TaskInstance

 

def get_task_status(context):
    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    dag_id = task_instance.dag_id
    task_id = task_instance.task_id
    task_status = task_instance.current_state()

 

    return dag_id, task_id, task_status

 

# Example usage within a task
def my_task_function(**context):
    dag_id, task_id, task_status = get_task_status(context)
    print(f"Task status for DAG '{dag_id}', Task '{task_id}': {task_status}")

 

# Define your BigQueryOperator task
my_bigquery_task = BigQueryOperator(
    task_id='my_bigquery_task',
    ...
    on_success_callback=my_task_function,
    on_failure_callback=my_task_function,
    ...
)
```

`Error` : TypeError: my_task_function() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the below code for your second approach:

**Demo.py**

```
def get_task_status(context):
    task_instance = context['task_instance']
    dag_id = task_instance.dag_id
    task_id = task_instance.task_id
    task_status = task_instance.current_state()
    return  dag_id,task_id,task_status

def my_task_function(context):
    dag_id, task_id, task_status = get_task_status(context)
    print(f"Task status for DAG ID :: '{dag_id}', Task ID :: '{task_id}' Task Status : {task_status}")


with DAG(dag_id='removed',start_date=datetime(2021, 4, 5, 15, 0),schedule_interval='@daily',catchup=False) as dag:
    t1=BashOperator(task_id="first",bash_command='echo starting')
    t3=BashOperator(task_id="secound",bash_command='echo end')
    t2 = BigQueryOperator( task_id='RunLoadJobWhenSourceModified',   sql='select * from my-project.dataset.table; ', use_legacy_sql=False,on_success_callback=my_task_function)

    t1>>t2>>t3
```

**LOG**

[image]

In the above code, I passed one argument to the function instead of keyword arguments and the function worked as expected. For more information about callbacks, you can refer to these [airflow official documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/administration-and-deployment/logging-monitoring/callbacks.html#callbacks) and [stack thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65967548/airflow-on-failure-callback).